# node js mongo aggregate does not work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate-functions

Hello i am using Node js in combination with Async. I'am trying to use an aggegrate statement to mongodb. I have succesfully execute this statement in the MongoDB shell but it does not work with Node.

The statement within Mongo Shell is:

```
db.stgOmniTracker.aggregate([{ $match: {State:"Solved" } },{ $group: {_id: {lastChangeWeek: "$lastChangeWeek", lastChangeYear: "$lastChangeYear"}totalCount: { $sum: "$count" }} })
```

The statement which i use in node is:

```
var  request = require("request")
    ,async = require('async')
    ,mongo = require('mongodb')
    ,d3 = require('d3')
    ,uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/commevents'
    ,moment = require('moment')
    ,underscore = require('underscore')
    ,actWeek = actualWeek()
    ,actMonth =  actualMonth()
    ,ftlrGroup = []
    ,fltrState = []
    ,compareWordGroup = null
    ,compareWordState = null
    ,locals = {}

exports.getTickets = function (req, res, next) {

    console.info('-------------------Get Tickets --------------------------------------------------------')

    mongo.connect(uri, function (err, db) {
        console.info('MONGODB START CHECK COLLECTIONS')
        var tasks = [  
            // Load stgOmniTracker - prepare measureSet rawtotCreatedPerWeek
            function (callback) {
                db.collection('stgOmniTracker').aggregate([ { $group: {_id: {creationWeek: "$creationWeek", creationYear: "$creationYear"}totalCount: { $sum: "$count" }} }]).toArray(function (err, rawtotCreatedPerWeek) {
                    if (err) return callback(err);
                    locals.rawtotCreatedPerWeek = rawtotCreatedPerWeek;
                    callback();
                });
            }]
        console.info('--------------- START ASYNC ------------------------')
        async.parallel(tasks, function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            var rawtotCreatedPerWeek = locals.rawtotCreatedPerWeek
            db.close()
        })
```

I get the following error back from node:

```
/home/erik/git/WisdomAsAService/views/Dashboard/getTickets.js:xx
                    db.collection('stgOmniTracker').aggregate([ { $group: {_id: {creationWeek: "$creationWeek", creationYear: "$creationYear"}totalCount: { $sum: "$count" }} }]).toArray(function (err, rawtotCreatedPerWeek) {
                                                                                                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Do you know how i can fix this problem?

Manny thanks,

Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not valid. It seems to me that you are basically missing a comma.

`SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` usually means that you have a token at an unsuitable place which is not understood by javascript. The best(or rather the easiest) way to tackle these errors is by using a static code analyzer like eslint, flow or sonar qube.

These tools integrate well with popular editors as well.